# Invalid Column Name in 'Where' Expression

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I found this SQL function that iterates over the table and it finds the **ParentID** the code works except when I put a where clause in it doesn't work on the newly created column. If I don't use the where clause it produces **Expr1** as the root of the tree which is what I want but I can't put a condition on it.

Can someone help me fix this problem?

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_Root
(
    @PostID int
)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @R int

SELECT @R = CASE WHEN ParentPostID = 0 THEN PostID
                ELSE dbo.fn_Root(ParentPostID)
            END
        FROM Post
        WHERE PostID = @PostID

RETURN @R
END


SELECT PostID, Title, dbo.fn_Root(PostID) AS Expr1
FROM Post WHERE Expr1 = 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible workaround: you can put the calculated value in the `WHERE` clause again:

```
SELECT PostID, Title, dbo.fn_Root(PostID) AS Expr1
FROM Post 
WHERE dbo.fn_Root(PostID) = 5
```

Comment: Does this evaluate the function twice?  Does it depend on whether the function is flagged as deterministic in SQL, or does it somehow cache it for each row of the output?

Answer (score 3):

You can't refer to a calculated / computed column alias directly in a `WHERE` clause in SQL Server.  However, one trivial work-around is to wrap the statement and place your `WHERE` clause on the outside, referring to the computed column:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT PostID, Title, dbo.fn_Root(PostID) AS Expr1
    FROM Post)
WHERE Expr1 = 5
```

Comment: "You can't refer to a calculated / computed column directly in a WHERE clause in SQL Server".  That statement is incorrect (see @ChristianSpecht answer).  What you cannot do is refer to a column alias in the WHERE clause.